# building gcc 4.9.2 with Java enabled; top_builddir not found

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-mavericks

Building gcc fails if Java is enabled and the command make is run from another make file (an automation script).

The process run smoothly if Java is either not enabled or when i goto build directory and type make from terminal.

This happens in OS X 10.9.4

Any ideas?

In example is this a standard variable created by auto-sth depending on MAKELEVEL or what?

Thanks,
Ev. Drikos

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'Java is enabled'? Are you referring to an environment variable or the java binary being in the PATH?

Comment: configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,java

Comment: closed; the workaround was to exclude explicitly java from stage1 languages and reset PATH to default.